# cannot show message box dialog

Tags: php, ajax

I have this code:

```
function delTempBill() {
    if ($('#bills_ID').val() == '') {
        popUpMessage("Error", "choose bills to delete", 2);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "DelTempBill.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                draft: "ok",
                bills_ID: selectedTempId
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data2) {
                if (parseInt(data2) > 0) {
                    $("#tempBills" + selectedTempId).remove();
                    popUpMessage("Done", "Bills was Delete", 2);
                    newGrid();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code is to delete bills from table, when I call this function the bill was deleted but the message cannot show.

Why ?

Comment: Where you have defined **popUpMessage** function? Make sure it is available in current script.

Comment: Just check whether it satisfies your condition that parseInt(data2) > 0 and it shows any error using Firebug console..

Comment: @Dr. Dan popUpMessage function is define on the same page and i will change it to alert("") and the same i canot see message box

Comment: @Edwin Alex no error on firebug :(

Comment: then put alert inside      if (parseInt(data2) > 0) {.. Check whether the alert is fired..

Comment: then the problem is on your data2 value.. Just check wat value it is returning. right now it fails to satisfy the condition  if (parseInt(data2) > 0). So it must be less than or equal to 0 (or) some other value..